# comparison between partially ordered group and Semifield

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, lattice-orders

I would like to compare [partially ordered group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_group#:%7E:text=%20A%20group%20G%20is%20a%20partially%20ordered,%E2%88%88%20H%20then%20a%20%3D%200%20More%20) $(G,\cdot,\leq)$ and [semifield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semifield) $(S,+,\cdot)$.
Here I want to find out the main differences between them. The similarities are clear for me. I think one of the main differences is the total weak order $\leq$. That means, the  order $\leq$ is directly connected to the partially ordered group, but not for the semifield. Please any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do they have in common?

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen Both are groups under multiplication, but G is not commutative.

Comment: SO I presume they have pretty much everything else  as difference (in particular, as $\leq$ may be empty). --- (And OT: First time I read the title, I heard a bass theme play in my head ;) )

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen Thanks. But in the wikipedia, it says "division is always possible for semifiled: i.e., for every a and every nonzero b in S, there exist unique x and y in S for which b·x = a and y·b = a." So, could it be one of the differences? For instance, in the case of partially ordered group, the set of positive rational numbers is not divisible under multiplication (i.e x^2=2 has no solution in Q^+).

Comment: Let me precise the definitions (as the terminology sometimes varies): A semiring $S(+, . )$ is an algebraic structure where $S(+)$ is a commutative semigroup, $S(\cdot)$ is a semigroup and the (usual) distributive law holds. The semiring $S$ is a parasemifield  if $S(\cdot)$ is a group and a semifield if there is a multiplicatively absorbing element $w\in S$ such that $(S\setminus\{w\})(\cdot)$ is a group.

Comment: Now, every parasemifield has an order (compatible with $+$, $\cdot$ and $^{-1}$) given by $a \leq b$ if $a=b$ or there is $c\in S$ such that $a+c=b$. Every additively idempotent parasemifield (i.e. $a=a=a$ for every $a\in S$) is nothing else than a lattice-ordered group where $a\wedge b=a+b$ and $a\vee b=(a^{-1}+b^{-1})^{-1}$. So a parasemifield is simply a generalization of the notion of a lattice ordered group. Another examples are for instance the positive rationals $\mathbb{Q}^+$ etc.